# Can sp_executesql be configured / used by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I am looking at an application that uses highly dynamic sql queries against SQL Server. Looking at the queries that are constructed in very weird and complicated ways, but that's a different story, I tell it to give a good reason for me being not able (too stupid) to find things out myself... I can't see any code where the queries are wrapped with `sp_executesql`.

But when I trace, I can see a lot of queries coming in wrapped with `sp_executesql`. The whole application solution does not even contain the command `sp_executesql` at all.

So I wondered if there is kind of a configuration I do not know yet that forces the software to wrap queries with sp_executesql by default?

What could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason the SQL statements are getting wrapped with `sp_executesql` is the setting of the `SqlCommand.Commandtype` property **and passing any Parameters to the command.**

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc1", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 1);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The code above ends with this T-SQL:

> ```
> exec proc1 @param1=1
> ```

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc1", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 1);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

This code ends with execution of the following T-SQL:

> ```
> exec sp_executesql N'proc1',N'@param1 int',@param1=1
> ```

**Addition 23.12.15:** Using a `CommandType.Text` command, the results are similar: As soon a parameter is added to the command object, .NET will  wrap the whole query into `sp_executesql` and pass the parameters to it.

**Addition:** After diving deeper into `sp_executesql`, parameter sniffing and plan caching this behavior of the .NET classes totally makes sense in order to avoid high frequent query compilation and number of plans. So it's basically designed to ensure a better SQL Server performance in general while it at the same time could lead to poor performance of some queries (parameter sniffing issue) that are used with different parameter values than the initial created query plan.

See:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/
- [http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql](https://www.itprotoday.com/database-performance-tuning/don-t-fear-dynamic-sql)
- [http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/)
- http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/
- https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql

The above sample were created using .NET Framework 4.5 and SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a .NET application, then it is very likely a result of [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) being called. According to the main [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx#Anchor_7) class page, in the grid of method descriptions in the "Remarks" section, under **ExecuteReader** it says:

> Executes commands that return rows. For increased performance, ExecuteReader invokes commands using the Transact-SQL **sp_executesql** system stored procedure. Therefore, ExecuteReader might not have the effect that you want if used to execute commands such as Transact-SQL SET statements.

I do not have time now to test this to confirm their description, but it should be easy enough to create a simple console app that does a very simple call, passing in some query text, and including a parameter that is supplied with a `SqlParameter`. My guess is that `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteScalar` also use `sp_executesql` since they also allow for passing in parameters, so why would there be a different path for how those are executed?